# Calling i18n.js file on app's entry-point | svelte-i18n

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, snowpack

I am trying to internationalize my Svelte app.

I am using Svelte with Snowpack. And svelte-i18n. I follow their tutorial on GitHub.

In the [tutorial](https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-i18n/blob/main/docs/Getting%20Started.md#4-initializing), they say :

> "Note: Make sure to call your i18n.js file on your app's entry-point.
> If you're using Sapper, remember to also call init() on your
> server-side code (server.js)."

I don't know how to do it? Can anyone please help me?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point is the file where you initialize your app. If you are using the [default Svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template), the entry point is `src/main.js`. You can place the i18n code there.

```js
import App from './App.svelte';
// copied from https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-i18n/blob/main/docs/Getting%20Started.md#4-initializing
import { register, init, getLocaleFromNavigator } from 'svelte-i18n';

register('en', () => import('./en.json'));
register('en-US', () => import('./en-US.json'));
register('pt', () => import('./pt.json'));
// en, en-US and pt are not available yet

init({
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    initialLocale: getLocaleFromNavigator(),
});
// starts loading 'en-US' and 'en'

// now render your app
const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'world'
    }
});

export default app;
```

The package also provides a [template](https://github.com/kaisermann/sapper-template-i18n) for doing this in Sapper.

Comment: I did your suggestion but it didn't work for me. I am using svelte with snowpack. Could you please help me? I don't know why it is not working. I'm following the tutorial and no error is showing. Just a blank page.

Comment: Can you make a GitHub repo demonstrating the issue? It's hard to tell what's going on with the context you've provided.

Comment: Thank you! I posted a new question with my GitHub repo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145620/svelte-i18n-with-snowpack-shows-blank-page-without-errors

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Svelte with Svelte Kit, and I can't find any entry point like `main.js` or `App.svelte` anywhere, but putting the code in `__layout.svelte` works for me.