# Adding and preserving i18n basepath on Routify

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, routify

I want to use an i18n basepath on Routify.

In other words, my URL is like this: `www.example.com/about-us/`

And I want to change it to this: `www.example.com/[CURRENT_LANGUAGE]/about-us/`

I've followed [the example](https://routify.dev/examples/i18n-basepaths) provided on the official website but it didn't work for me. When I add the `/ru/` or `/en/` prefix it works. But when I change the URL by clicking `href` it removes the prefix but goes to the desired URL. I need to have the prefix in the new URL as well.

I think I need to change my `href`s to adopt the new basepath logic. But not sure how to do it. How can I solve this issue? Any help is very much appreciated.

My build info: [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/), [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/), [Routify](https://routify.dev/), [Svelte-i18n](https://github.com/kaisermann/svelte-i18n).

GitHub repo: [Click here](https://github.com/ulvidamirli/my-Routify-i18n-basepath-problem)

Answer (score 2):

I tried copy pasting your `App.svelte` to the starter template, but it works as expected. The language was retained when navigating.

If you're trying to change the active language, you have to

- A) update the `lang` value in your `App.svelte` or
- B) use `window.location.href = '/en/some/page'`

If you're using plain `href`, you need to include `$url`. Ie. `<a href={$url('/about')>about</a>` or `<a href="/about" use:$url>about</a>`. Otherwise, your URLs won't be rewritten. https://routify.dev/docs/helpers#url

Comment: JakeDK, thank you very much for your help! I didn't know how to change the hrefs. I think it would be better to include it in 'i18n basepath' example. I tried $goto($page.path); to change the basepath when changing the language from dropdown but it didn't work for me. Isn't it for changing basepath? I followed your script from https://github.com/roxiness/routify/issues/332#issuecomment-780500138

Comment: I see that  $goto($page.path) changes the URL but it changes it to the exact same without trailing slash.

Comment: I can't see how you've implemented the script you link to. If you're interested I can send you an invite to our new auto generated templates repo. Then you can generate a template with the features you need.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that. I updated index.svelte and about-us.svelte and included the script I am talking about. Yes, sure it would be awesome, my email is u.u.damirli@gmail.com if you prefer to not disclose it in a comment. I'm using Snowpack, I hope it is compatible with it.

Comment: I'll need your github name to share the repo. Github couldn't find you by email.

Comment: My GitHub username is ulvidamirli

Comment: Hey Jake, I didn't get any invitation. Just wanted to let you know.

Comment: Hi Ulvi. I just checked and it says your invite is pending. Could you check your email?